# mod_wsgi is not allowing external access to flask app

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I am using mod_wsgi on a lamp server where I am trying to deploy a Flask app, but it is not visible from outside my LAN. I have setup my main app to use the app.run(host='0.0.0.0'), it is also not in debug mode. I have the iptables for the server setup as...

```
    target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I blocked the 5000 port because from my lan the server is accessible from these settings.

This is my wsgi file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/SnakeByte/SnakeByte")
from SnakeByte import app as application
```

This is my file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/SnakeByte

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName snakebyte.us

        WSGIDaemonProcess SnakeByte user=user1 group=group1 threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/SnakeByte/SnakeByte.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/SnakeByte/SnakeByte/>
            WSGIProcessGroup SnakeByte
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}  
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is the rest of your web server externally accessible?

Comment: I suppose not, seeing as a connection to port 80 hangs.